# How can i make a text input to start the number 9?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mask

I need a textbox to start with the number 9, how do i do it?
The textbox only accepts numbers but i need it to start with the number 9.
I've tried it like this but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
            var $phone = $("#phone");
            $phone.mask('900000000', {reverse: false});
        });
```

Comment: Set a value? `$phone.val( $phone.val() || "9");`

Comment: That worked but it can be deleted, is there a way to not allow it to be deleted?

Comment: You need a textbox to start with 9 & you need the value to not be deleted - so does the textboxes value always have to start with 9? If so, then you could add the value 9 to the textbox after it has been submitted - so give it a value of 9 and also once submitted, run a check to see if it starts with 9 and if it does not append it to start with 9?

Comment: Yes, the values needs to always start with 9. I'm going to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
   //get the input element to const
   const $phn = $('#phone');
   //add keydown event
   //if value is a length of 1 and code is backspace or delete return false
   //if length is longer than 1 and delete key is pressed, reset to just 9
   $phn.on('keydown', function(e){
       const code = e.which || e.keyCode;
       //keycode 8 = backspace, keycode 46 = delete
       if($phn.val().length === 1 && (code === 8 || code === 46)){
          return false;
       }
       else if(code === 46){
          $phn.val('9');
          placeCursor($phn);
       }
   });
   
   //initialize value to 9 and place cursor
   $phn.val('9');
   placeCursor($phn);
   
   //function to focus and place cursor in input box
   function placeCursor(input){
      $(input)[0].focus();
      $(input)[0].setSelectionRange($(input).val().length, $(input).val().length);
   }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" />
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```